# Statement in 'else' is getting printed multiple times but I want it to print only once when 'if' is wrong

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Here, I am comparing array elements of an array of user IDs and passwords.
I want the `else` statement to get printed only once when the `if` condition is wrong.

Can I take any other variable for it? Or can someone suggest if I can use a `break` statement anywhere.

```
      public static void main(String args[])
       {
        lib1 o=new lib1();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int u[]={51,52,53,54,55};
        int p[]={1,2,3,4,5};
        int d=0;
        System.out.println("enter username and password");
        int un=in.nextInt();
        int pw=in.nextInt();

        for(int i=0,j=0;i<5 && j<5;i++,j++)
        {
            if(un==u[i] && pw==p[j])
            {
                while(d==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("enter subject name");
                    String c=sc.nextLine(); 
                    if(c.equals("java"))
                    o.java();
                    else if(c.equals("exit"))
                    {
                        d++;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {   
                System.out.println("invalid password"); 
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add if statement in end as shown in bold in code below.

public static void main(String args[])
           {
            lib1 o=new lib1();
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int u[]={51,52,53,54,55};
            int p[]={1,2,3,4,5};
            int d=0;
            System.out.println("enter username and password");
            int un=in.nextInt();
            int pw=in.nextInt();

            for(int i=0,j=0;i<5 && j<5;i++,j++)
            {
                if(un==u[i] && pw==p[j])
                {
                    while(d==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("enter subject name");
                        String c=sc.nextLine(); 
                        if(c.equals("java"))
                        o.java();
                        else if(c.equals("exit"))
                        {
                            d++;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
            **if(d == 0) {
                System.out.println("invalid password");
            }**
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a `break` at the end of your `else` block. This will allow you to immediately exit the for loop.

Comment: but sir, it will go out of loop after  if(un==u[0] && pw==p[0]) is false but what IF  if(un==u[1] && pw==p[1]) is true .

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void main(String args[])
   {
    lib1 o=new lib1();
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int u[]={51,52,53,54,55};
    int p[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int d=0;
    System.out.println("enter username and password");
    int un=in.nextInt();
    int pw=in.nextInt();

    for(int i=0,j=0;i<5 && j<5;i++,j++)
    {
        if(un==u[i] && pw==p[j])
        {
            while(d==0)
            {
                System.out.println("enter subject name");
                String c=sc.nextLine(); 
                if(c.equals("java"))
                o.java();
                else if(c.equals("exit"))
                {
                    d++;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {   
            System.out.println("invalid password"); 
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

This is a quick fix to your problem, but you could have other implementations as well

Comment: have already tried it sir, but it is printing else statement even if IF is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `break` statement anywhere in your loop where you want the loop to be exited instantly. That means you can put it in your `else` block, or your `if` block, or wherever you need to break from. In a nested loop, a `break` statement will only break from the immediate loop that it is called in.

Also, in your code you create two `Scanner` objects that use `System.in` as the input source. This is not recommended because if one `Scanner` is closed, the other one will also be closed. Instead, create only one `Scanner` object and close it only when you are completely finished with it.

Comment: is it possible to take String and Int both type of input by just one Scanner at a time?

Comment: @Deeptank You can get both `String`s and `int`s from one `Scanner` object. That means that you can call `scanner.nextInt()`, or `scanner.nextLine()`, etc., all with the same `Scanner`.